# How to print a Binary Tree diagram (vertical) and ensure fairly unbalanced trees are not improperly printed?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to write functionality to print a vertical binary tree diagram,
[image: as seen here.]

I've got the correct breadth-first search algorithm written, and it outputs the BFS-ordered tree traversal to an integer vector. The code can be seen below:

```
void bst::printlist(Node* node)
{
    std::queue<Node*> travQueue;
    std::vector<int> result;

    travQueue.push(node);

    while (!travQueue.empty())
    {
        result.push_back(node->val);
        if (node->prev != NULL)
        {
            travQueue.push(node->prev);
        }
        if (node->next != NULL)
        {
            travQueue.push(node->next);
        }
        travQueue.pop();
        node = travQueue.front();
    }
}
```

However, I am completely stumped on how to convert the resultant vector to one that accurately represents all missing nodes that exist as gaps in a fairly unbalanced tree, [image: such as this one?]

For this example, the vector would only be filled with the integers in the left-to-right order, when it would need to contain information for every missing node all the way down to the bottom level. When going to write the actual code to print the tree with ASCII characters, I will need this information if I am to be able to determine where to and where not to draw nodes -- so, I planned to include dummy values at these gaps to distinguish.

Does anyone have any recommendations for ways to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: You can push `prev` and `next` to `travQueue` even if they are `nullptr`. When you reach a `nullptr` in your iteration, add the dummy value to the result and two more `nullptr` to `travQueue` for the non-existing children.

Comment: @NicoSchertler, that is a genius solution! I've worked it out, and that works flawlessly. I think I just have to test to make sure I'm only doing this as long as we don't exceed the known largest height of the tree, or else it'll go on forever adding null leaf nodes. Thank you so much! (Would you mind to post your comment as a question reply so I can flag it as the answer?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a great answer, thanks to @NicoSchertler:

"You can push prev and next to travQueue even if they are nullptr. When you reach a nullptr in your iteration, add the dummy value to the result and two more nullptr to travQueue for the non-existing children."

And here's my code for it:

```
std::queue<Node*> travQueue;
    std::vector<int> result;

    int h = treeheight(root) + 1;
   
    travQueue.push(node);

    for (int i = 0; i < pow(2, h) - 1; i++)
    {   
        node = travQueue.front();
        if (node != nullptr)
        {
            if (node->prev != nullptr)
            {
                travQueue.push(node->prev);
            } else
            {
                travQueue.push(nullptr);
            }
            if (node->next != nullptr)
            {
                travQueue.push(node->next);
            } else
            {
                travQueue.push(nullptr);
            }
        } else
        {
            travQueue.push(nullptr);
            travQueue.push(nullptr);
        }
        if (node != nullptr)
        {
            result.push_back(node->val);
        } else
        {
            result.push_back(-1);
        }
        travQueue.pop();
    }
    return result;
```